# Globally share variables

Tags: templating, globals

I have 4 main template folders, under the /craft folder (each template folder works for another subdomain).

Now, I do have per template folder, a few variables that I like to have shared amongst all templates underneath it.

Such as:

```
{% set projectsGroup = "projectsWeather" %}
{% set sliderGroup = "sliderWeather" %}
{% set faqGroup = "faqWeather" %}
```

Which are different, per template folder.

Now, when I put these variables at the top of my master _layout file, this gets shared nicely amongst all templates -- that is, for those that use this _layout file.

I do however also have a few json generation template files, that can not use the _layout file.

My question now is how to elegantly assign these variables, and do this only once.

I can not stick them in a separate file and just use "include" or "extend", because then _layout either ignores or complains.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them to [the `environmentVariables` section](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#environmentVariables) of your config file, and retrieve them using [the `craft.config` template tag](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.config).

For example:

```
// Config 
"environmentVariables" => [
    "color" => "blue",
]

// Template
{{ craft.config.environmentVariables.color }}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping for a more isolated solution (per template folder), but this will do fine as well.

Comment: You can create nested arrays in the environment variables array, to "scope" your variables..